# Reproducibility tensorflow in python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm following this examples in order to tweak neuron networks in tensorflow.
https://github.com/mrdbourke/tensorflow-deep-learning/blob/main/01_neural_network_regression_in_tensorflow.ipynb

Specially for **the model_1**

```
# Set random seed
tf.random.set_seed(42)

# Replicate original model
model_1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

# Compile the model
model_1.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
                metrics=['mae'])

# Fit the model
model_1.fit(tf.expand_dims(X_train, axis=-1), y_train, epochs=100)
```

So the model should be reproducible but :
When I try with
`tf.random.set_seed(42)`
the model prediction change at each execution
Whereas when I use
`tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(42)`
the model is reproducible

Moreover I don't get the same result with this code

```
tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(42)

# Create the model
model_1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)    
])

model_1.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
    metrics=["mae"]
)


model_1.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=100)
```

example's one : mae = 30.638134 mse = 949.13086
mine : mae =  8.629547 mse =  80.97771

I checked that my training and testing data are the same. I checked that my model and the exemple's model are the same. Do you have some clues to figuring out ?

Training and testing sets :

```
X=tf.range(-100,100,delta=4)
y=X+10
X=tf.expand_dims(X,axis=1)
y=tf.expand_dims(y,axis=1)
X_train = X[:40]
y_train = y[:40]
X_test = X[40:]
y_test = y[40:]
```

Comment: Hi, @momo33 could you complement your question by showing us how you split between the training and testing datasets?

Comment: Maybe this can help you too: https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/reproducibility_recipes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs of](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/set_random_seed) `tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed`, it "sets all random seeds for the program", which includes `random.seed`, `numpy.random.seed` and `tensorflow.random.seed`.
Going with your example, the following modified code creates deterministic results:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import random

X_train = tf.range(10)
y_train = tf.zeros(10)
# Set random seed
# tf.random.set_seed(42)
# tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(42)
random.seed(42)
# Replicate original model
model_1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

# Compile the model
model_1.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
                metrics=['mae'])
model_1.build(input_shape=(None, 1))
print(model_1.weights)

# Fit the model
model_1.fit(tf.expand_dims(X_train, axis=-1), y_train, epochs=100)
```

I included the `model.build` step to compare the model weight(s). They are the same every time.
It seems that tf.keras uses the `random` library to create the weights. Setting its seed to a fixed value creates the same results.

As for your question why this is different:

> example's one : mae = 30.638134 mse = 949.13086 mine : mae = 8.629547 mse = 80.97771

You concluded rightly that `tf.random.seed` does not yield deterministic results. Therefore, the results it the notebook are random and not reproducible, as they set the wrong seed. If they would run the notebook again, they would get another result.

Answer (score 0):

i advice to use this function to reproduce the same results, this code is collected from tens of sources

```
# installing torchmetrics library to our colab notebook
# !pip install torchmetrics

# importing the libraries
import os
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

# This function to be able to reproduce the same numbers in the future, by fixing
# the algorithms parameters that lead to generate the same random numbers

# printing pytorch version as this point may affect the reproducability if diffrent pytorch version used
print(f'using version {tf.__version__}')


# fix random number generation aka regenerate the same random numbers every time (such as weight and bias initialization )
def set_random_seed(seed=7, deterministic=True):
    """Set random seed, for python, numpy, tensorflow

    This function to be able to reproduce the same numbers in the future, by fixing
    the algorithms parameters that lead to generate the same random numbers

    Args:
        seed (int): Seed to be used.
    """
    
    #
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seed)

    # set seed for python random numbers.Set `python` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
    random.seed(seed)

    # set seed for numpy random numbers. Set `numpy` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
    np.random.seed(seed)

    #GLOBAL SEED:- set seed for tensorflow random numbers.  Set `tensorflow` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value                                                 
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)

    # tf gpu fix seed, please `pip install tensorflow-determinism` first
    os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'


    # sets seeds for keras
    tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(seed)


    # forcing tensorflow to use single thread since multiple threads are potential source of un-reproducibility
    # Configure a new global `tensorflow` session
    session_conf = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
    tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)

    # # if if speed is less important than reproducibility then un-comment this line, as it will reduce the calculations-speed significantly but will leads to more robust reproducibility
    # tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()

seed=7
set_random_seed(seed=seed)
```